# Finding a special prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples, factorial

The prime number $$p=82\ 954\ 517$$ has the property that the numbers $$2!+p,3!+p,\cdots , 11!+p$$ are all prime, but $12!+p$ is composite.
Upto $10^{10}$, the only other prime with this property is $105\ 204\ 557$

> Does a prime $p$ exist such that $$2!+p,3!+p,\cdots , 12!+p$$ are all prime ? If yes, which is the smallest such prime ? Such a prime must exceed $10^{10}$

Update : The prime $$p=79\ 017\ 245\ 897$$ is even better than what I wanted. $j!+p$ is prime for $j=2,3,4,\cdots,13$. Now it remains to find the minimum primes for the limit $12$ and the limit $13$

Comment: I extended the search to $2\cdot 10^{10}$ , still no example.

Comment: 5 mod 6, not 29 mod 30, etc.

Comment: Before reading the whole question, I said to myself, the author must be Peter. And I was right :)

Comment: @Klangen it’s Peter either at the prime of life, or at the life of prime :)

Comment: did my sieve work ...

Comment: https://oeis.org/A256301 confirms that the solutions you give are optimal, interesting the way the sequence jumps.

Comment: not really, we know that by the first one we are dealing with the lower of a pair of twin primes, making it 5 mod 6, next one eliminates 29 mod 30 because adding 6 isn't coprime, next one eliminates 11 mod 30, because 24 is -6 mod 30 lands on not coprime etc.

Comment: @Klangen Yes, prime numbers are always fascinating. I search for new discoveries (although I would not be surprised if someone even had this idea before). That there is always someone downvoting such questions , is annoying, but I simply ignore it. In fact, the smallest example with limit $13$ is the one mentioned in the question. Upto this limit, we neither have limit $12$, so the above prime actually is the champion.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee In fact, the only possible residues modulo $210$ are $17$ and $107$. But already for $2310$, the number of possibilities is $10$.

Comment: considering 2310=11*210 that's about 50% elimination.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee True. Based on those residues, you are invited to extend my table, for example to find an example which holds upto $j=14$. Did you continue upto $30\ 030$ ?

Comment: @KSab The bad news is that someone else had this idea before. But that it becomes more and more difficult to find even one more prime, is not really surprising. How far does the table go ?

Comment: @Klangen Unfortunately, I was right that this idea is not new :(

Comment: if I haven't screwed up the math ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've only found the number you've found yourself as well:

```
79017245897 is a candidate
    79017245897 + 2! (== 2) = 79017245899 is prime
    79017245897 + 3! (== 6) = 79017245903 is prime
    79017245897 + 4! (== 24) = 79017245921 is prime
    79017245897 + 5! (== 120) = 79017246017 is prime
    79017245897 + 6! (== 720) = 79017246617 is prime
    79017245897 + 7! (== 5040) = 79017250937 is prime
    79017245897 + 8! (== 40320) = 79017286217 is prime
    79017245897 + 9! (== 362880) = 79017608777 is prime
    79017245897 + 10! (== 3628800) = 79020874697 is prime
    79017245897 + 11! (== 39916800) = 79057162697 is prime
    79017245897 + 12! (== 479001600) = 79496247497 is prime
    79017245897 + 13! (== 6227020800) = 85244266697 is prime
```

I did this using an exhaustive search (I've calculated all the prime numbers up to 160,000,000,000 and then checked for each prime if the above sums are in the list). This also shows that 79,017,245,897 is the smallest prime with this property.

I'll repeat it now for factorials up to 12! and add it here as soon as it has finished.
Will there be a maximum? I mean will there be a number $n$ such that there doesn't exist a prime $p$ for which $p + i!$ is prime for all $i \in \{2, \ldots, n\}$.

---

As promised, my results for $n = 12$:

```
 79017245897 is a candidate
148165314371 is a candidate
```

IOW, 79,017,245,897 is the smallest both for $n = 12$ and $n = 13$.

Comment: probably if an equivalency class covering shows up.

Comment: I guess there is no maximum. The generalized Bunyakovsky conjecture predicts infinite many solutions for every limit $n$, but this conjecture is of course open. And I doubt that we can continue until, lets say , $n=30$

Comment: If I double check my math I might be able to ...

Answer (score 2):

Just a few restrictions:

- first leads to p is 5 mod 6
- second eliminates 29 mod 30
- third eliminates 11 mod 30
- fourth eliminates 6 mod 7 ( aka 167,83 mod 210)
- fifth eliminates  1 mod 7 ( aka 197, 113 mod 210)
- sixth eliminates 9 mod 11
- seventh eliminates 6 mod 11
- eighth eliminates 10 mod 11
- ninth eliminates  1 mod 11
- tenth eliminates  12 mod 13
- eleventh eliminates 1 mod 13
- twelvth eliminates  14 mod 17
- thirteenth eliminates 9 mod 17
- fourteenth eliminates 16 mod 17
- fifteenth eliminates 1 mod 17
- sixteenth eliminates 18 mod 19
- seventeenth eliminates 1 mod 19
- eighteenth eliminates 19 mod 23
- nineteenth eliminates 12 mod 23
- twentieth eliminates  22 mod 23
- twenty first eliminates 1 mod 23
- twenty second eliminates 7 mod 29
- twenty third eliminates 23 mod 29
- twenty fourth eliminates 24 mod 29
- twenty fifth eliminates 15 mod 29
- twenty sixth eliminates 28 mod 29
- twenty seventh eliminates 1 mod 29
- twenty eighth eliminates 30 mod 31
- twenty ninth eliminates 1 mod 31
- thirtieth eliminates 4 mod 37

okay I have messed up ( prior) we need -n! mod q# eliminated. table updated (fixed) and extended.

Comment: realized it mostly doesn't matter if I've screwed the math once you look deep 6, and 1 mod 7 would switch orders if I screwed up, but so would 1 and 10 mod 11, and 12 and 1 mod 13, so at least for those pairings as long as you go to $n=p-1$ won't matter as by wilsons theorem p-1! = -1 mod p and p-2! =1 mod p